# Strange hibernate cache behaviour

Tags: java, hibernate

I use ehcache and hibernate 3.6.7 Final. This a pseudo code sample that reveals problem with caching.

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class A{    

    long id;    

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aId", targetEntity = B.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    protected Set<B> fieldB;
}    


@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class B { 

    long id;

    long bId; 
}
```

1) First time when I load entity A from hibernate it does not read fieldB. And this is ok - cause  FetchType.LAZY is set.

2) Second time when I load entity A  I see sql queries retrieving entity A JOIN entity B.

3)If remove @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN) point 2 will not be performed.

So the question is this bug or feature? And how can I avoid such latent things.

Comment: You can try asking also on the Hibernate Forums. And if you are brave enough (and have time), debug using Hibernate source code.

Answer (score 1):

You have two conflicting fetches, you definitely do not want to specify the fetch on the column and the @Fetch annotation as it will provide unpredicatable behavior.